# Installing fork of package under a separate name

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I'd like this use [this fork](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2568) of statsmodels and call it statsmodels_beta or something and be able to use both in Python (i.e. import statsmodels; import statsmodels_beta).

I tried running

```
$pip install -e git+https://github.com/josef-pkt/statsmodels.git#egg=statsmodels_beta
```

... but it wouldn't let me import it. Note that this is being done in a virtualenv that has the normal statsmodels already installed.

Comment: Given url is not a path for Git repository, it's a HTML page with a wall of text.

Comment: Fixed, sorry -- that wasn't the problem though, just shoddy question writing

Comment: Sorry to revive an old thread, but have you found a way to do it? I have the exact same question but couldn't find anything useful. I can install an editable version of the package, but I doubt if there is a way to do what you asked.

Comment: Oops, just saw this. I'll add an answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (in a given virtualenv):

```
source ~/env/bin/activate
pip uninstall statsmodels
pip install -e git+https://github.com/josef-pkt/statsmodels/tree/absorb_fixed_effects#egg=statsmodels
cd ~/env/src/statsmodels
git checkout -b absorb_fixed_effects
git pull origin absorb_fixed_effects
```